# PERC 5/i and SSD

Tags: ssd, dell-perc

I have a PowerEdge 2950 with PERC 5/i and 4x 300GB 10K SAS drives in RAID 10. I want to add a secondary RAID 0 virtual disk using 2x SSD in the extra two slots. I know I'll need a 2.5" -> 3.5" adapter for each SSD, but I have read conflicting reports that solid state drives are or are not compatible with PERC 5/i controllers.

Will this setup work?

Thanks!

-Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my Dell guy, yes it should work.  However, due to the PERC 5i's lack of NCQ support, you will not achieve the IOPS you would see on a PERC 6i.  I have also just verified that the 2950 can be easily upgraded to PERC 6i, which is what I will be doing prior to switching to SSD.

Also, I'm really happy with this 2.5" -> 3.5" adapter:  http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817994083

Its connectors are properly located to slide directly into a RAID chassis.  Most adapters I've seen would not work.